# Problema con LOGIN en C

Tags: c

estoy comenzando a estudiar lenguaje C y quiero hacer este programa que le pida al usuario que ingrese un USERNAME y password, y le de 3 intentos y finalice.
Pero me figura el error:

> Warning, passing argument 1 of strcmp makes pointer from interget without a cast  (en la línea 14)

dejo el código:

```
// INGRESO A HOMEBANKING CON 3 INTENTOS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USERNAME "oso"
#define CONTRASENIA "1234"
#define LONGITUD 80

int main(){ 
   char username[LONGITUD +1];  // 80 para el usuario y 1 para el caracter nulo 
   int contrasenia;
   int intentos=3;
   
   printf("\n\tBIENVENIDO AL HOMEBANKING.");
   
   do {
// system("cls");
   if(strcmp(contrasenia, "1234") ==0){
    printf("BIENVENIDO, OSO.");
    break;
} else {
    printf("\n\tUSUARIO Y/O CLAVE INCORRECTO.");
    printf ("Tienes %d intentos", intentos);
    intentos--;
} while(intentos > 0 );
   
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `contrasenia` es un entero, y `strcmp` espera un `char*`, a eso de deve el error. La solucion seria simple, guarda la contraseña como un string en lugar de un entero.

Comment: tal y como te dijeron, cambia el tipo de dato de `contrasenia` haciendo `char* contrasenia;`

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` es una función que compara cadenas de caracteres, luego `contrasenia` no puede ser de tipo `int`

```
char contrasenia[LONGITUD];
```

> y si quiero que contraseña sea un INT?

Entonces no puedes usar `strcmp` sino que deberás usar el operador de comparación (y convertir `"1234"` en `1234`, ya que no se pueden comparar enteros con cadenas de caracteres):

```
if (contrasaenia == 1234)
```

Comment: y si quiero que contraseña sea un INT? porque intento declarar contraseña como un int y después no puedo hacer la verificación si contraseña es correcta, mostrar bienvenida al login, no me lo toma porque no sé como hacer bien el if(contrasenia==0)

Comment: @ASC revisa la respuesta, la acabo de editar para responderte

Comment: realicé los cambios sugeridos pero me dice: 
 if(contrasenia = 1234) {
    printf("BIENVENIDO, OSITO.");
    break;

[error] assignment to expression with array type

Comment: @ASC se te olvidó cambiar `contrasenia`... `int contrasenia;`

Comment: y en este error que sucede?

variables: 
char username [20];
int contrasenia = 1234;

if(strcmp(username, "oso") == 0) && (contrasenia == 1234){
[Error]: expected identifier before '(' token

Comment: @ASC esto no funciona así, te respondo por esta vez, peero los comentarios no deberían funcionar como un chat. Lo que sucede es que el paréntesis que abre el if lo cierras justo antes de `&&`. En consecuencia, `&& (contrasenia==1234)` no pertenece a la condición del if, pero tampoco es una instrucción válida por si sola... de ahí el error

Answer (score 0):

código editado en base a sugerencias de @eferion y @Christian:
todavía no funciona, me sigue tirando errores como 'assignment to expression with array type' en if (contrasenia == 1234){

```
// INGRESO A HOMEBANKING CON 3 INTENTOS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define USERNAME "oso"
#define CONTRASENIA "1234"
#define LONGITUD 80

int main(){ 
   char username[LONGITUD + 1];  // 80 para el usuario y 1 para el caracter nulo 
   char contrasenia[LONGITUD];
   int intentos = 3;
   
   printf("\n\tBIENVENIDO AL HOMEBANKING.");
   
   do {
// system("cls");
    printf("\n\tINGRESE SU USUARIO: ");
    scanf("\n\t%c", &username);
    
    if(username == "oso"){
        printf("BIENVENIDO, OSO");
    } else {
        printf("USER INCORRECTO");
    }
    
    printf("\n\tINGRESE PASSWORD: ");
    scanf("\n\t%c", &contrasenia);
    
   if(contrasenia = 1234) {
    printf("BIENVENIDO, OSITO.");
    break;
} else {
    printf("\n\tUSUARIO Y/O CLAVE INCORRECTO.");
    printf ("Tienes %d intentos", intentos);
    intentos--;
} //while(intentos > 0 );
 }while(intentos > 0 );
return 0;
}
```

Comment: tampoco funciona el bucle while de intentos

Comment: Si este código no soluciona el problema, no es una respuesta. Si no es una respuesta, este no es su sitio. Esto no es un foro tipo chat donde la gente comenta sus impresiones sino un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Aquí resolvemos dudas, pero tu también tienes que poner de tu parte. Necesitas estudiar las reglas del lenguaje y familiarizarte con las mismas... no podemos ni vamos a hacerte todo el trabajo

Comment: Nunca pedí que me hagan el trabajo, ni siquiera es uno. Pido orientación porque estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje y obviamente no tengo conocimiento al 100% de C, therefore here I am. 
Es complejo para todos los que nunca programaron y recién empiezan. Lo mismo sobre stackoverflow, en vez de decirme: tu comentario no va acá-- podrías decirme dónde va, o dónde están las normas.

Comment: A ver, StackOverflow no es un foro al uso. Este tipo de contenidos en plan, te solucionamos un problema ... te surge otro dos líneas más abajo, y luego resulta que además has escrito mal alguna parte de la solución y no te funciona ... lamentablemente este tipo de historias no encajan aquí. Todos aquí hemos tenido que aprender en algún momento un lenguaje de programación y hemos pasado por lo mismo que estás pasando tu, por ello te digo que debes intentar esforzarte por, manual en mano, intentar comprender los errores que te salen y por intentar corregirlos por tus propios medios.

Comment: Lee el código con atención, analízalo (no pienses que una línea es de una forma determinada, léela con tranquilidad, solo así podrás encontrar algunos errores tontos). Yo entiendo tu postura y no intento meterme ni contigo ni con tus conocimientos, solo avisarte que tienes que poner más de tu parte. Piensa que si te resolvemos todos los errores tontos nunca vas a aprender ... no vas a aprender a leer los mensajes de error ni vas a aprender a solucionar los problemas por ti mismo. Es un consejo